# C++ Builder 11.1 Android can't write a file to the Shared Documents folder

Tags: android, c++, permissions, c++builder

I am having difficulty with C++ Builder 11.1 Android trying to write a file to the Shared Documents folder.  It worked with C++ Builder 10.3.1 but it doesn't work in 11.1

I have the permissions set properly in the Project Options Dialog box:
Dangerous - Read External Storage = true
Dangerous - Write External Storage = true

In the OnFormCreate method, I put in the necessary run time permissions as follows:

```
String FPermREAD;
String FPermWRITE;
DynamicArray<String> permissions;

FPermREAD  = JStringToString(TJManifest_permission::JavaClass->READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
FPermWRITE = JStringToString(TJManifest_permission::JavaClass->WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

permissions.Length = 2;
permissions[0] = FPermREAD;
permissions[1] = FPermWRITE;

PermissionsService()->RequestPermissions(permissions, LocationPermissionRequestResult);
```

In the routine to write the file...

```
AnsiString SharedPath;
AnsiString FileName;
FILE *OutStream;

SharedPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetSharedDocumentsPath(); 
// SharedPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents"

FileName = SharedPath +"/"+MyFileName;
OutStream = fopen(FileName.c_str(),"wb");  // This fails in 11.1 but not in 10.3.1
if(OutStream) {
     // write the file here
     fclose(OutStream);
     }
```

My Android device is Android 10.
Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use the `OnCreate` event in C++, use the constructor instead. And you should check with `PermissionsService()->Is[Every]PermissionGranted()` before calling `PermissionsService()->RequestPermissions()`.  But more importantly, if you do call `RequestPermissions()`, you need to check the result to make sure the permissions were actually granted before you perform the action you wanted permissions for. In the code provided, you are requesting write permissions to external storage, but there is nothing shown that indicates whether you were actually granted that permission.

Comment: Thanks Remy!   So the sub folder you talk about should be a folder underneath the Documents folder like /storage/emulated/0/Documents/MyApp ???

Comment: Mister Lebeau is not talking about sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

Add requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file.

Comment: blackapps,  could you be a little more specific as to how to do that.  I am new to Android.  I am assuming you add the legacy storage tag via the uses permissions section in the Project Options dialog box???  There is no entry for legacy external storage there.

Comment: The nature of the program that I am working on talks to a hardware device, takes information from the hardware and stores it in a file on the Android phone or tablet.  The Phone or Tablet is then hooked up to a windows computer via USB cable and the file MUST be accessible via windows explorer to transfer it to a computer for use with other software.

This works if I set the android programs folder to the Home Path but it is not seen by windows.  What folder should I use?

Comment: `. I am assuming you add the legacy storage tag via the uses permissions section ` No. I said to add it to application tag. Add it to AndoidManifest.xml file directly.

Comment: Blackapps,  I found out what the problem was.  Before I installed RAD Studio 11.1, I uninstalled version 10.3.1.  It didn't remove all the files in the C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0 folder which had the old AndroidManifest.template.xml file which it was copying to my project folder.  After a bit of cleanup, it now fetches the template from the C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0 folder which is the correct one for RAD Studio 11.1.  This template file has the request legacy storage tag in it so all is good.  Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I switched the development of this program from my Samsung Galaxy S9+ (Android 10) to a Samsung Tablet (Android 11).  I keep getting page faults and exception class Aborted (6) errors in the constructor of one of the forms.  Is there any suggestions you guys might have as to how to track down these kind of errors?  What would be really nice would be to have a debugger option like code guard to find these types of bugs.

Comment: Remove all code from constructor. Then add code line for line.

Comment: In the constructor of the form that causes these errors, there is no code.